# Связать текст с динамической переменной в запросе

Tags: mysql, sql

Как правильно сделать выборку?

Есть две таблицы, в них нужно сделать выборку по совпадению двух полей.

Запрос:

```
SELECT * 
FROM oc_product_description AS pd, oc_url_alias AS ua 
WHERE 'product_id='+pd.product_id = ua.query
```

`pd.product_id` поле имеет значение 928, а `ua.query` имеет значение в виде `product_id=928`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE CONCAT('product_id=', pd.product_id) = ua.query
```